# Updating an object in a Collection

Tags: php, class, oop

> I'm using a Collection class to store objects of 'players'. Now in my Bet class I want to update the points of one of the players.. But I think I'm only updating it in once instance of my Collection. I'm not quite sure how to talk to the global collection object. Here's my code

**Index.php** I'm creating a new PlayerCollection and passing it to my Parser class

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($twig) {

    try {
        $players = new PlayerCollection();
        $matchParser = new MatchParser($players);
        $matches = new MatchCollection($matchParser->parse('../data/data.json'));
    } catch(JsonException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    echo $twig->render('home.html', [
        'matches' => $matches->all(),
        'players' => $players
    ]);

});
```

**Parser Class** I'm accepting the PlayerCollection in my constructor and setting the Player object in the Bet class using the following code.

*The this->players->find() functionality is tested and returns the correct object from the collection*

```
$bet = new Bet();
$bet->setPlayer($this->players->find($name));
```

**Bet Class**

```
class Bet {

    private $player;
    private $teamHome;
    private $teamAway;
    private $scoreHome;
    private $scoreAway;


    public function getPoints($scoreHome, $scoreAway)
    {
        if($scoreHome == $scoreAway ) {
            $this->player->setPoints(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function to calculate the score inside my Twig template

```
{{ bet.getPoints(match.getHomeScore(), match.getAwayScore()) }}
```

When I echo out the score of the player inside my bet class it's working.. But my PlayerCollection hasn't updated on my index.php page.

#### It might be my Template? The value's I want to update are already placed by twig, only later in the template I call the method to update the variables previous, but already placed

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You are only adding points to the player inside the Bet class. That has no effect on the actual player object inside the Parser object

Comment: Should I update the original Collection with the new player after the points increase?

Comment: This is missing something. I tried this http://codepad.org/TpprZ5ZE and it seems to work as expected. In theory anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Maybe the index overwrites the newer created one, I'll add the code

Comment: I updated the index.php code, You can see I pass the $players to my twig view.. Maybe this is not the right behaviour from my part?

Comment: Thanks for your time, isn't & deprecated since php5.4? I'm trying without the find() method now.

Comment: It's my own collection class, I'll add it to my code., as well: It might be my Template? The value's I want to update are already placed by twig, only later in the template I call the method to update the variables previous, but already placed

Comment: Not too familiar with twig but maybe this helps: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

Answer (score -1):

when you created your new `Bet()` object, you copied an existing instance of one of your player objects into your Bet object, thus not altering the original one.

*code that was previously here didn't make sense, oops*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The parser actually parses different content then the players. Is there maybe another way?

Comment: look, your player attribute in your Bet class is a copy of the player in your PlayerCollection object